# Get cursor position in a game before it is re-centered

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to record my in-game mouse movement so I can play it back. The game is Call of Duty 4, although that isn't relevant to this question. What is relevant is that most First Person Shooter games re-center the mouse cursor when you move it, so that you never hit any borders. I can't find anything about this online after searching for a while. I am currently using a mouse hook (WH_MOUSE) in order to keep track of the mouse movements (WM_MOUSEMOVE). When I list these messages, I can see that the cursor is pulled back to screenResolutionX / 2, screenResolutionY / 2 (the center of the screen).

My first attempt at figuring this out was to ignore the messages if they are equal to the center of the screen, so that when I play back these mouse movements, the re-centering is ignored. I assumed this would solve the problem, but now when I play back the mouse movements the mouse goes too far (way off from what I recorded). When I do the same recording/playing back in the main menu of the game (where the cursor isn't re-centered), the playback is incredibly accurate. My question is: what can I do to record mouse movements in the game accurately, given that the game re-centers my cursor?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit: let me clarify what I'm asking. I want to only record actual user mouse input, not the game re-centering the mouse cursor.**

Comment: Sounds like you should intercept the mouse messages **before** they get sent to the game's window. Though I'm not sure how exactly would one go about doing that, TBH

Comment: I've come across that SO post, however I don't agree that a driver/filter is necessary to accomplish what I'm trying to do. That would only be the case if I wanted to intercept the mouse data before it gets to Windows, instead I want to intercept it before it gets to the game -- but without the re-centering. Maybe there's a way to determine the origin of the mouse message, and if it was sent by the game process then I ignore it? I couldn't find anything like this though..

Comment: "Windows" is an overloaded term. In the context above the "window" means "game's window", not the "Windows the OS"

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't a response to you, but to the other guy linking an SO post. But people keep removing their comments or something.

Comment: If you want to record genuine mouse input, use [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In order to intercept those mouse messages you'd have to make a filter driver or a hook. Here's a nice article (with code) on the subject:

http://www.oblita.com/interception.html

That article is based on this [Windows API: SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx) and shold be a good starting point for you.

Comment: I'm using a Windows hook, as I mentioned in the original post. However, the game also sends re-centering WM_MOUSEMOVE messages. I receive those as well, which means I can't determine the actual mouse movement (because sometimes the WM_MOUSEMOVE includes a small movement of the mouse AND the re-centering, so I can't filter it out). I don't think a filter driver is necessary to accomplish what I want. Intercepting isn't the problem -- I want to be able to distinguish the re-centering from actual mouse input.

Comment: Since you know the geometry of your screen and current mouse position (if anything - at least based on previously intercepted mouse move messages) you can always tell if the mouse move message is targeting its move to the center. Is that not true?

Comment: But how could I distinguish the using moving the mouse back closer to the center versus the game re-centering?

Comment: I suppose only by whether the move was "closer" to a center or "dead to" the center?

Comment: That's what I thought, so I filtered out the messages that moved it back to the exact center, but the result is awful. The code works perfectly in applications that don't re-center the mouse though.

Comment: I still think that [MouseProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644988(v=vs.85).aspx) and [LowLevelMouseProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644986(v=vs.85).aspx) are what you are looking for.

Comment: But I'm already using MouseProc. That's how I'm getting the WM_MOUSEMOVE messages in the first place.

Comment: I'm curious if using WM_INPUT (raw input) would solve my problem.. I'd much rather have a different option though.

Comment: Maybe the [JournalRecordProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644983(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: I think the problem here is that this will still capture the WM_MOUSEMOVE messages that the game sends to re-center the cursor.

Comment: @R.Loh: Have you verified, that the game actually does send (or post) `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages? Those input messages are generated by the system in response to `SendInput` as well. In case the application does the right thing and calls `SendInput`, a low-level mouse hook can filter this input by checking for the `LLMHF_INJECTED` flag in the [MSLLHOOKSTRUCT structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970.aspx) passed to the hook procedure.

Comment: Now that's something I can work with. I will try that out and let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [Low Level Mouse Hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986(v=vs.85).aspx)? It intercepts mouse messages earlier than just mouse hook.